# Loading specific versions of DLLs with win32com in python

Tags: python, win32com

I'm currently using win32com to Dispatch a COM object:

```
company=Dispatch("SAPbobsCOM.Company")
```

This DLL actually exists in 2 version in my environment, 32 and 64 bit. 
Can I actually control which version of the COM object is loaded, or is that somehow tied up in python version?